# VB6 can't CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, createobject

This VB6 code (Crystal Report 10) seemed to work before

```
Dim CR As CRAXDRT.Application
Set CR = CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")
```

It now does an `Error 13`

A workaround is

```
Dim CR As New CRAXDRT.Application
```

How can a `New` succeed if `CreateObject` fails?

What can make `CreateObject` fail while it worked a few hours before?

Comment: The object is not actually initiated in an `As New` statement. Your object actually initiates the first time it's used. So have you used the variable `CR` in your testing yet?

Comment: Yes, CR now works in the rest of the code

Comment: Well Error 13 is a type-mismatch error. Are you sure that `CrystalRuntime.Application` and `CRAXDRT.Application` are the same thing? You should be able to `Dim CR As Object`, `Set CR = CreateObject(...)`, then type `MsgBox TypeName(CR)` and see if it's what you think it is.

Comment: OK I'll do that. But my question is actually why don't this work anymore? I was rushed to correct this problem

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing early binding and late binding to begin with. Late Binding = `Dim CR As Object`, `Set CR = CreateObject(...)`; Early Binding = `Dim CR As CRAXDRT.Application`, `Set CR = New CRAXDRT.Application`. If you have the references in place, why not just do all early binding? But to answer your question, this is usually due to versioning. Does the reference have a new version / update? `As CRAXDRT.Application` could be referring to v1, while `CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")` could be referring to v2 - which would be a type mismatch. Don't mix early/late binding.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I agree, if you are going to use strict typing, late binding doesn't seem to have much benefit / purpose

Comment: According to the user, nothing has been done on the computer, at 8:00 it was working, at 12:00 it wasn't. Should I trust the user? :)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs you are right about the version issue, my investigations have shown that there has been an installation that might have changed the ActiveX versions. So: never trust a user :D